# Inserting extra records into coredata by parsing xml web service

Tags: objective-c, ios, insert, xml-parsing, duplicates

I am having an issue with inserting records into CoreData after parsing XML webservice. I parse the web service and store the records in an array and the count i get for array is 239. Before i insert the data i see the array count for existing core data.Its 0 records. So now i push the data into the coredata. All goes well. But, i end up with 1 extra record. A duplicate for an existing record. The count i get is 240.HOw is it happening?I did this process with another table.I got from the webservice for this new table table this time 113 records. After i insert the data, the table has 114 records and 1 extra record(duplicate again). I check using the firefox add on sqlite manager. Peculiar thing to note is that there is a field (not the one i designed) called Z_OPT, which has the value 239 (remaining fields identical) and for the table with 113 records the 114th record has z_OPT= 113(remaining fields identical).Did this happen to anyone?Any information would be of great help. If you need more information, please ask.Thanks...

Comment: Any pattern for which one gets duplicated?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, but the problem changes now. The record that is being inserted now is 0.i.e. i end up with 240 records again( of which 239 are correct and non-zero), but one record for which all the fields that i designed are 0 .The other fields which came with SQLite Manager are non-zero. Why is the 1 zero field record being inserted?Thanks..